# Predefined C++ Types (compiler internal) Not Found error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm attempting to write a game of tic tac toe just for fun and am running into this error when I try to debug the application. The error occurs on line 23, the multidimensional std::array declaration. I can't find any material on the subject or come up with my own solution. The error shows up in a "Source not found" tab in VS 2019, doesn't look like a normal error, and this is the text: "**predefined C++ types (compiler internal) not found**
You need to find predefined C++ types (compiler internal) to view the source for the current call stack frame."

```cpp
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <string>

class tic_tac_toe
{
private:
    enum class values
    {
        X,
        O,

        max_values
    };
    struct square_data
    {
        std::string code{};
        values value{};
    };
    std::array<std::array <square_data, 3>, 3> board{};
public:
    tic_tac_toe()
    {
        for (int a{ 0 }; a < 3; ++a)
        {
            for (int b{ 0 }; b < 3; ++b) { 
                switch (a)
                {
                case 0:
                    board.at(a).at(b).code = "A";
                    board.at(a).at(b).value = values::max_values;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    board.at(a).at(b).code = "B";
                    board.at(a).at(b).value = values::max_values;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    board.at(a).at(b).code = "C";
                    board.at(a).at(b).value = values::max_values;
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cout << "initializer failed\n"; //shouldn't happen
                }
                board.at(a).at(b).code.append(std::to_string((b + 1)));
            }
        }
        print_grid();
    }

    void print_code(square_data square)
    {
        switch (square.value)
        {
        case values::X:
            std::wcout << L"X";
            break;
        case values::O:
            std::wcout << L"O";
            break;
        default:
            std::wcout << L" ";
        }
    }

    void print_grid()
    {
        fflush(stdout);
        int previous{ _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT) }; //print unicode
        for (int a{ 0 }; a < 3; ++a)
        {
            switch (a)
            {
            case 0:
                std::wcout << L"\n┌───┬───┬───┐\n│ ";
                break;
            case 1:
                std::wcout << L"\n├───┼───┼───┤\n│ ";
                break;
            case 2:
                std::wcout << L"\n├───┼───┼───┤\n│ ";
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "printer failed\n";
            }
            for (int b{ 0 }; b < 3; ++b) {
                print_code(board.at(a).at(b));
                std::wcout << L" │ ";
            }

        }
        std::wcout << L"\n└───┴───┴───┘\n";
        fflush(stdout);
        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), previous); //for switching back to narrow output
    }
};

int main()
{
    tic_tac_toe game{};

    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Once I added `#include <io.h>` and a `main` function I had no trouble compiling and running your code. Can you explain in greater detail exactly what you are doing? I assume you're trying to step into something in the debugger. What happens if you step over that line or just step out when it can't find the source?

Comment: @RetiredNinja the code does indeed compile just fine and it works how I expect so far. But debugging fails as when I step into line 23. If you step out when it throws the error all that happens is debugging ends and when you step over the line it still throws the error. Edited to fix the io.h not being there. Since it's the third line that executes from main() it basically makes debugging impossible, and debugging will be necessary for completing the game.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. There is no `main` in the code you show.

Comment: Use Debug > Step Out when you accidentally stepped into code that the debugger can't show source for.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error of VS. It works when I remove /permissive-. This [problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-message-predefined-c-types-compiler-internal/1176546) has already been reported.

Comment: This works, thanks!